# Proteus and RTC (DS1307) issue with I2C and accuracy

Tags: c, timer, embedded, i2c, atmega

I'm using Proteus software and I2C with the DS1307 RTC. What I'm trying to do is to store the time and date into variables, and view this through the watch window. I think I've done this in a nice and structured way (for my skill level), but the problem is that if I take out all delays, it won't work.

The time elapses on Proteus ends up going super slow, and although the date and time is right, it freezes at that point (sometimes after starting up the program, I have to delete the variables from the watch window and re-add them to get them to work, but that might be besides the point). The delays make it work... but... add a delay. This ends up making each second in Proteus equal 1.5 seconds in real time. It's slow.

Prof said Proteus would do that a great deal, to a much worse degree, but that it should still grab the time (since the DS1307 is **initialized** from PC clock). This doesn't make ANY sense to me. If it's off in Proteus, how could it possibly grab it? I digress. He says there shouldn't be any delays, and I do agree, but it won't progress without them. Here's the code, I hope you guys can shed some light.

Edit: Forgot to say I'm using the Atmega328p, external clock at 16MHz, unprogrammed divide by 8. PCB package is SPDIL28.

If there's any other info you guys need, I can share it first thing in the morning. Thanks.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "I2C.h"
#include "ds1307.h"

void Wait()
{
   uint8_t i;
   for(i=0;i<20;i++)
      _delay_loop_2(0);
}

char ss[3], mm[3], hh[3], dd[3], nn[3], yy[3], x[2];    // Appropriately labeled variables
uint8_t data;                                           // Now Read and format time

void main()
{
   I2CInit();                               // Initialize i2c Bus
   DS1307Write(0x07,0x10);                  // Blink output at 1Hz
// PORTB|=((1<<PB2)|(1<<PB1)|(1<<PB0));     //Enable Pull ups on keys
   while(1)
      {

     /* SECONDS */
     _delay_loop_2(0);
     DS1307Read(0x00,&data);            // Read seconds address
     ss[2]='\0';                        // Cap end of seconds string
     ss[1]=48+(data & 0b00001111);      // The 4 seconds bits into the first seconds digit
     ss[0]=48+((data & 0b01110000)>>4); // The 3 seconds bits into the last seconds digit

     /* MINUTES */
     _delay_loop_2(0);
     DS1307Read(0x01,&data);            // Read minutes address
     mm[2]='\0';                        // Cap end of minutes string
     mm[1]=48+(data & 0b00001111);      // The 4 minutes bits into the first minutes digit
     mm[0]=48+((data & 0b01110000)>>4); // The 3 minutes bits into the last minutes digit

     /* HOURS */
     _delay_loop_2(0);
     DS1307Read(0x02,&data);            // Read hours address
     hh[2]='\0';                        // Cap end of hours string
     hh[1]=48+(data & 0b00001111);      // The 4 hours bits into the first hours digit
     hh[0]=48+((data & 0b00110000)>>4); // The 3 hours bits into the last hours digit

     /* DAY */
     _delay_loop_2(0);
     DS1307Read(0x04,&data);            // Read hours address
     dd[2]='\0';                        // Cap end of hours string
     dd[1]=48+(data & 0b00001111);      // The 4 hours bits into the first hours digit
     dd[0]=48+((data & 0b00110000)>>4); // The 3 hours bits into the last hours digit

     /* MONTH */
     _delay_loop_2(0);
     DS1307Read(0x05,&data);            // Read hours address
     nn[2]='\0';                        // Cap end of hours string
     nn[1]=48+(data & 0b00001111);      // The 4 hours bits into the first hours digit
     nn[0]=48+((data & 0b00010000)>>4); // The 3 hours bits into the last hours digit

     /* YEAR */
     _delay_loop_2(0);
     DS1307Read(0x06,&data);            // Read hours address
     yy[2]='\0';                        // Cap end of hours string
     yy[1]=48+(data & 0b00001111);      // The 4 hours bits into the first hours digit
     yy[0]=48+((data & 0b11110000)>>4); // The 3 hours bits into the last hours digit
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this code all running inside the Proteus simulation?

Comment: Yes it is. Time is lagging.